# Git pull, fatal: loose object

Tags: git, corrupt

My colleague tried to do a `git pull` from our master.  He got this error:

```
$ git pull
fatal: loose object f7630cc30248df1e19bcb40c9de1b60b71cdfce1 (stored in ./objects/f7/630cc30248df1e19bcb40c9de1b60b71cdfce1) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Luckily, my repo seems not to be corrupt, and I do have a copy of `f7630cc30248df1e19bcb40c9de1b60b71cdfce1`.  But I can't figure out what he needs to do with it.  We tried just taking my copy & putting it in his `.git/objects/f7/` directory, but the error message stays the same.

Is it supposed to be as simple as just shuffling files around, or do we need to do something else?

Comment: This question has better answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-can-i-fix-the-git-error-object-file-is-empty/31110176, maybe it should be flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does that file exist loose on the master? If so, is it valid or corrupt there? Yes, it should be sufficient just to copy a good version of the file into the objects directory.

Comment: It's there on the master, but I'm not sure how to tell whether it's loose, how can I do that?

Comment: if it's present in `.git/objects/f7/`, that's what "loose" means (i.e. not "packed" into `.git/objects/pack`)

Comment: Oh!  Okay, great - when he's back tomorrow, we'll try copying it directly.  I'm guessing some cygwin->Windows->server->colleague->copy->paste step corrupted my copy of the file.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem wasn't corrupt file contents, it was too-restrictive file permissions on the repository.  We're just using a file server as our repository, which sucks.  We need to switch to a server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the .git/objects directory for files not readable by you.  I had this problem and that was the issue.  A coworker had cloned my repo while the central server was down, and (I think) a push ended up putting files owned by him but not readable by me.