# Data corruption using git

Tags: git, data-recovery, data-retrieval, corrupt-data

I was working on a project and experienced hardware failure.  I have about 30 commits I did not get to push before this happened.  I recovered from the crash and checked my repo.  I now get this error message from a `git status`.

```
error: object file .git/objects/a8/f43fd5a872feda2a771e6a1ced1518f455d9f3 is empty
error: unable to find a8f43fd5a872feda2a771e6a1ced1518f455d9f3
error: object file .git/objects/a8/f43fd5a872feda2a771e6a1ced1518f455d9f3 is empty
fatal: loose object a8f43fd5a872feda2a771e6a1ced1518f455d9f3 (stored in .git/objects/a8/f43fd5a872feda2a771e6a1ced1518f455d9f3) is corrupt
```

How can I remove this empty object and not get an error message from the HEAD?

I tried manually removing the bad object, but got this error:

```
fatal: could not parse HEAD
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597003/how-to-remove-fatal-loose-object) are likely going to be helpful for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure)

Comment: My problem as a little simpler.  I just did the steps below. Thank you for the consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Makato. I voted your comment up.
I came up with my own quick and dirty solution.

1. I went to ~/my_project/.git/logs/refs/heads/
   In that directory used sublime text editor to open the file named: master 
   (this file contains a history of commits)
2. I went to the last line of code.  It contained NULL, NULL, NuLL repeated over and over again. I deleted it and saved the file.
3. In the last good line of commits you will see 2 commit strings with 40 characters in each string.  I copied the second string of characters.
4. I went to this directory next. ~/my_project/.git/refs/heads
   In that directory used sublime text editor to open the file named: master 
   (this file contains the last commit in your history)
5. I pasted the commit string I copied earlier and saved the file.
6. I ran a git status, and it stated my branch was ahead of origin/master by 29 commits.
7. I pushed my commits.
8. Ran another git commit, and it committed changes that should have been in that corrupt commit.
9. Now I am back to where I left off.

I hope this helps anyone that experiences this problem.