# how to fix GIT error: object file is empty when switching branch

Tags: git

i am in the branch `master`. when checkout to `zc` branch , i was informed `object file is empty`.

```
$ git branch 
  demo
  develop
* master
  zc

$ git checkout zc
error: unable to find 00d2a5741d54116a156e477093c3fcf30b24c6b3
error: unable to read sha1 file of doc/build/html/_sources/props/buyhp.txt (00d2a5741d54116a156e477093c3fcf30b24c6b3)
error: object file .git/objects/ee/4fc9118d213089e959b1625405c4b835cd4af7 is empty
error: unable to find ee4fc9118d213089e959b1625405c4b835cd4af7
error: object file .git/objects/ee/4fc9118d213089e959b1625405c4b835cd4af7 is empty
fatal: loose object ee4fc9118d213089e959b1625405c4b835cd4af7 (stored in .git/objects/ee/4fc9118d213089e959b1625405c4b835cd4af7) is corrupt
```

Comment: did you edit doc/build/html/_sources/props/buyhp.txt  or change something about it? Did you change anything else?

Comment: if you don't edited some files under .git, you probably have some issues with your hard disc?

Comment: run `git fsck`, you have a corrupted repo. Also check for your HD health

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fix GIT error: object file is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty)