# What might cause a git error - corrupt loose object?

Tags: git

There are many posts here on Stackoverflow about how to fix your repository when you come across an error like this after doing a `git pull`:

> > error: object file .git/objects/48/088f00d90b0d27de65336bb9ed9a75b0cfed33 is empty
> >     fatal: loose object 48088f00d90b0d27de65336bb9ed9a75b0cfed33 (stored in .git/objects/48/088f00d90b0d27de65336bb9ed9a75b0cfed33) is corrupt

What I'm curious to know is: **what are examples of things that would cause this error to begin with?**

Some questions report things like their system rebooting or their battery dying in the middle of a git pull. This interruption causing the issue makes sense.

Then there are other questions who report that the issue repeatedly happening, such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219731/error-object-file-is-empty-git-objects-is-empty-fatal-loose-object), with no clear indicator as to why.

Comment: As a side note, this can be fixed, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111728).

Comment: @George The explanation from Linus cited in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27806920/94687 also explains much and helps to recover in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

These errors should not happen when changes to the Git repository are carried out using the Git client.  From the documentation, see [Object Storage](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Object-Storage) to learn how Git stores its objects:

1. Git constructs a header that starts with the type of the object
2. Git concatenates the header and the original content and then calculates
   the SHA-1 checksum of that new content
3. Git compresses the new content with zlib

A corrupt loose object is any object whose state deviates from this design (See also [What are the “loose objects” that the Git GUI refers to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709687/what-are-the-loose-objects-that-the-git-gui-refers-to)).

Besides a system reboot or a dying battery, other reasons include

- using a buggy third-party implementation of Git
- manually "cloning" using rsync, scp, or some other external tool without data integrity checks
- copying and pasting in Windows
- disk failure
- sometimes just a [blue moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_moon) could do it

If you're curious, try this contrived example:

```
$ git init bad-apple
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/bad-apple/.git/

$ cd bad-apple

$ touch README; git add .; git commit -m "Add a transitional fossil"
[master (root-commit) ca3ea96] Add a transitional fossil
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README

# Get the commit object id
$ git rev-parse HEAD
ca3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63

# Git tries to help you not shoot yourself in the foot
$ chmod +w .git/objects/ca/3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63

# Empty out the commit object file and you broke it
$ truncate .git/objects/ca/3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63 --size 0
error: object file .git/objects/ca/3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/ca/3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63 is empty
fatal: loose object ca3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63 (stored in .git/objects/ca/3ea9630c0f01afc286589c4072db9c43262d63) is corrupt
```

Comment: Not using 3rd party Git software, not doing any manual cloning, seeing it on Mac and PCs. Happening too consistently to be a blue moon. Puzzled as to what continues to cause this. Regardless, very useful answer - thank you!

Comment: Sounds painful.  If it's happening to multiple clients I would suspect the problem is with the remotes. I hope you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: How does "copying and pasting in Windows" cause a problem?