# Errors while running git gc --aggressive

Tags: git, ubuntu-12.04

While running 'git gc' I get the following errors:

```
    chris@chris-VirtualBox:~/code/dataquality$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 3849, done.
error: object file .git/objects/1e/6a84c4e4202c469c188b69fd23407fca44d69d is empty
error: unable to find 1e6a84c4e4202c469c188b69fd23407fca44d69d
error: object file .git/objects/95/9dbfcdfd3ef09088e652d4e5526df66bc53323 is empty
error: unable to find 959dbfcdfd3ef09088e652d4e5526df66bc53323
error: object file .git/objects/9c/3f15a856fda402d82131bb9ea35ea7d27ae05d is empty
error: unable to find 9c3f15a856fda402d82131bb9ea35ea7d27ae05d
error: object file .git/objects/cf/bdc18aab11c9cbada9fb1ac73c347352b7a4fb is empty
error: unable to find cfbdc18aab11c9cbada9fb1ac73c347352b7a4fb
error: object file .git/objects/db/0ee0587a14cc0cdfa43ccda0d0b2010c7701b6 is empty
error: unable to find db0ee0587a14cc0cdfa43ccda0d0b2010c7701b6
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3539/3539), done.
error: object file .git/objects/db/0ee0587a14cc0cdfa43ccda0d0b2010c7701b6 is empty
fatal: loose object db0ee0587a14cc0cdfa43ccda0d0b2010c7701b6 (stored in .git/objects/db/0ee0587a14cc0cdfa43ccda0d0b2010c7701b6) is corrupt
error: failed to run repack
```

I have no clue how to resolve the errors. What steps should I take?

When I run `git fsck --full` this is the output:

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:~/code/dataquality$ git fsck --full
error: object file .git/objects/1e/6a84c4e4202c469c188b69fd23407fca44d69d is empty
fatal: loose object 1e6a84c4e4202c469c188b69fd23407fca44d69d (stored in .git/objects/1e/6a84c4e4202c469c188b69fd23407fca44d69d) is corrupt
```

Comment: What's the output of `git fsck --full`?

Comment: looks like there is an empty and loose object, i added output to question

Comment: There are two possibilities - if none of those objects are actually referenced through a branch, commit, tree, etc., then the corruption is fairly harmless - make a clone of your repo (or re-clone from a different existing one) and continue on your way. If those objects are referenced though, I hope you have another copy of your repo somewhere that still has those objects in a non-corrupted state.

Comment: Should I?: push my current changes to github, delete the project locally, then clone from scratch?

Comment: You can try a local clone and see what happens.  `git clone /path/to/local/repo`.  Then run `git fsck --full` in the new clone and see if the errors are still present.

Comment: After the local clone those two items that output with git fsck --full are still present in the new repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `git fsck --full` returned the same errors on the new clone the corrupt objects are used in a branch.  The discussion section from `git help fsck` has this to say about your situation:

```
       Any corrupt objects you will have to find in backups or other archives 
       (i.e., you can just remove them and do an rsync with some other site in
       the hopes that somebody else has the object you have corrupted).
```

So if you have an older clone with this object you may be able to recover.  If you don't have a backup [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371337/166732) may be useful to you.

Comment: Thank You, I will try this tonight and comment back tomorrow.