# Issue while pushing to repository

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-svn

I was just pushing to master branch and in the mid of the process my laptop got shutdown. When I switch on again and trying to push to master branch its showing me this error.

```
error: object file .git/objects/ac/d6296a7d26aecbaf9f3df5c336122f1309c40a is empty
fatal: loose object acd6296a7d26aecbaf9f3df5c336122f1309c40a (stored in .git/objects/ac/d6296a7d26aecbaf9f3df5c336122f1309c40a) is corrupt
root@rootb-u12:proj$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Can anyne help please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12371337/101361

Answer (score 0):

Check your top most commit i.e. where HEAD is pointing currently.. It seems to be your HEAD commit is empty [no changes made?? ]