# Git reset = fatal: unable to read tree

Tags: git

Someone made a commit on the wrong branch so I tried to [move the commit to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-recent-commit-to-a-new-branch).  When I tried to roll back the commit, I got this error:

```
[user@server gitrepo]$ git reset --hard 9c2de3c0
fatal: unable to read tree 9c2de3c0af09fc07a84ff84b594beb5a6d489181
```

The object looks fine:

```
[user@server gitrepo]$ ls objects/9c/2de3c* -al
-r--r--r-- 1 git git 222 Aug 28 12:09 objects/9c/2de3c0af09fc07a84ff84b594beb5a6d489181
```

Why can't it read this object, and what do I do about that?

**Edit:** to distinguish my problem from others:

- Git's database doesn't *appear* to be particularly out of sorts.  Running `git fsck -full` shows only a few (~20) dangling blobs and one dangling commit.  Which [does not seem particularly alarming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514659/git-what-is-a-dangling-commit-blob-and-where-do-they-come-from/18515113).

Comment: @Gabriele: I looked at that post, but that question, and it's answer, pertain to a `broken link from  commit`.  I have no such error when I run `git fsck`.

Comment: 1) what does `git cat-file -t 9c2de3c0` show? 2) what does `git cat-file -p 9c2de3c0` show?  (I suspect at least one will also fail, but it's worth a quick poke at it)

Comment: @torek - 1) `git cat-file -t 9c2de3c0` = 'commit' 2) `git cat-file -p 9c2de3c0` = my message, 'MODULE: added similarterms (MM)'

Comment: Hm, what about the "tree" and "parents" parts (in the `-p` output)?  If you follow those IDs do they work?

Comment: Did you follow https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_to_fix_a_broken_repository.3F ?

Comment: @VonC: thanks, I've seen that section paraphrased elsewhere, but your link goes into enough depth that I stand a better chance of following it. It's going to be a couple weeks before I can get back to this & try it out though.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure/22694491

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem. Solved it by checking and fixing disk. Some files were corrupted.