# What is the parent of a Git commit? How can there be more than one parent to a Git commit?

Tags: git

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222920/2419531) when I got really confused. My understanding was that the previous commit is the parent of a commit.

Comment: A merge has two (or more) parents.

Comment: Commits form a directed acyclic graph; therefore, a commit can have zero or more parents. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26395521/2541573

Comment: @Jubobs: for some reason your link isn't clickable (stackoverflow weirdness?)—ah, better/fixed now, thanks. Meanwhile, should we close this as a duplicate of that question? (I think probably yes, despite the very different *form* of the question...)

Comment: @torek Thanks. My link was missing the `http` scheme. Fixed. I'd be in favour of closing as a dupe, but I'm wary of my new "instaclose" superpowers.

Comment: @Jubobs Heh, I was startled the first time I intended to "vote to close" and found that I had in fact "closed"...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The parent commit is the commit this current commit is based on. Usually:

- When you `git commit` normally, the current commit becomes the parent commit of the new commit that's introduced by the command.
- When you `git merge` two commits (or branches, whatever) without fast-forwarding, a new commit will be created with *both* commits as parents. You can merge more than two commits in that way, so the new commit may have more than one parent.

Essentially, the commit tree (or [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), if we want to be accurate) is made up of those parent<-child relationships, with the children (more "recent"<sup>[1]</sup> commits) point to the parents (less "recent"<sup>[1]</sup> commits).

The only exception is the initial commit (or any other root commits), which has no parents.

---

1. "recent" isn't exactly an accurate term, as you may have a very old branch on the one hand, and a very new one on the other. And a child commit may be a lot "older" than another commit which is a parent elsewhere.