# git push with backdate

Tags: git, github

I had to backdate my computer and without realizing pushed some changes to the remote git repository.
Now when I see the commits in the git web view, my commit is shown as backdated.
However, all the code has merged just fine it includes the changes from previous commits by other developers.

Will the backdate cause any problem ?
Please let me know.

Comment: You will have to define "cause problems". Git stores two date/time-stamps with each commit, but those dates have no real *meaning* to Git, they just allow you to show them or select commits according to their dates. Whether any other program wants to use them, and if so for what, is up to those other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge is done according to the commit history, a [3-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/6309)  based on a common ancestor.

It does not depend on the commit or author dates.

The commits are linked together through a [parent relationship in a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26395555/6309), no matter what their date is.

[image: http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/diagrams/18333fig0302-tn.png]
<sup>Source: "[Branching and Merging](http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/git-branch-and-merge.html)" from Eric C. Anderson</sup>