# Historically count unmerged git branches

Tags: git

I understand I can get the branches currently unmerged to `master` in git with

`git branch -r --no-merged master`

What if I want to see the same for a historical commit but consider the state of branches at that time (including branches that have since been deleted) and not the current branches?

And in the end all I need is a count. Ultimately I'm trying to answer this question:

For each day in the history of a git repo (or for the last X days/months) how many branches existed that were unmerged to master on that day?

Edit: To be clear I only need a count of unmerged branches given a specific commit. I don’t need branch names. I.e. if I could take a cross-section of the log output that shows history graphically and count the lines that represent all branches at any given commit I’d be in good shape. I just don’t want to have to build that out if someone already has.

Edit 2: What about counting commits that are older than the commit in question and have a shared parent and subtract those that have more than one parent. See this diagram:  [image]

Comment: You know you cant know when a branch was created. you can only "see" the last commit date in each branch

Comment: I can find the common ancestor between two commits, and I can see where a branch was merged, so I *think* this should be possible.

Comment: common ancestor means "to which commit this branch is updated to" not when it was created

Comment: Good point. So maybe this is impossible...

Answer (score 1):

The branch creation/deletion is not recorded in a Git repo (not to mention you can rename a branch at any time, move it or reset it at any time)

The only record you can find, *for a time*, is in [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) (records are pruned after 90 days).

The git repo only keep an history of the commits, and their associated graph ([the DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26395521/6309)). Branches are only ephemeral pointers to points in that graph, in order to facilitate working with it.

---

As for "counting commits" to determine non-merged branches (for a given past commit), you might consider the pseudo-algorithm:

```
n=0
for each branch b
  if c is part of b
    continue
  fi
  ca=common_ancestor(branch_of_c, b)
  if ca older than c
    n=n+1
  fi
fi
```

The key part is to [use git merge-base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549155/6309) in order to find the common ancestor.
If that common ancestor is older than the commit being considered: count the other branch.
If not, do not count it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I added a clarification to the question. Really all I need is a count, which should be discoverable by following the DAG. My git-fu just isn’t strong enough to know the right approach.

Comment: That is the all point of my answer: you can't. The DAG does not keep branch information.

Comment: @devguydavid Following your edited question, I propose a pseudo-algorithm to implement that branch count.