# What does GIT download?

Tags: git, download, branch

If I clone a repository with 3 branches. Is GIT smart enough to only download the changes between the branches or does it download all files repeatedly for all branches? And also, does it download all data from all branches at the beginning or waits till I switch the branch?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in your question? As it stands now, the question requires more or less a full Git tutorial. How familiar are you with Git's object model? Do you know what a blob, tree, commit, tag, annotated tag, signed tag, note, ref is? Do you know how they are represented on-disk? Do you know what a packfile is? How familiar are you with the network protocol (which is based on packfiles)? Do you know what `git fetch` is? Do you know what `git checkout` is?

Comment: I don't ask for a tutorial about git. Just how git handles the initial download of the branches. My focus is on how much bandwidth it will use and if I can safe a lot of bandwidth by only fetch one branch (`--single-branch`).

Comment: In most situations, bandwidth should not be a concern.  But if you have a huge repo (lots of versions of large files that don't diff well, and you haven't used a tool like lfs to mitigate this), or a limited network connection, such that it *does* become an issue, then `--single-branch` and or shallow cloning can save considerable bandwidth at the expense of certain operations being less well-informed.  (Note that git operates locally for almost everything it does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is GIT smart enough to only download the changes between the branches or does it download all files repeatedly for all branches?

The best thing about git (from all the ones which came before git) is that is uses a DAG to keep track of changes. That is when you `git pull` or `git fetch` it only downloads the `diff`s. 
So to answer your question: It only downloads the 3 commits you've made. Then just make a local DAG for you. Have a look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) for a quick git basics.

> And also, does it download all data from all branches at the beginning or waits till I switch the branch?

When you do a `git clone` you download the whole repository, this is done to build the DAG. Then later on it only downloads the ones you ask it to, using `git fetch` and `git pull`.

`git fetch` downloads the changes from remote and store it in `.git/refs/remotes/<remote>/`. So you won't directly bring it into your `working directory`. (Have a read on git baiscs if you don't know what a `working directory` is).
`git pull` does `git fetch` and `git merge` in one command.

Refer to this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357) on fetch vs pull .

**A few reading materials**
Git looks like a tree more than a graph. [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395521)
A simple intro to git with explaining how and why we use a DAG [Link](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/)

Answer (score 2):

The currently-accepted answer is rather misleading, and a lot of what it says doesn't really address the question.

Only the packed representation[1] is used for transfer between repos, so you can generally assume that you'll receive a (reasonably) minimal representation of the information you requested.

To say that it "only downloads the commits" is misleading for several reasons.  Mostly it promotes the misconception that commits, themselves, are lists of changes - which they are not.  Commits are snapshots of the project[2].  "Downloads the commits" means, roughly, "downloads everything".

Which is a nice segue to...

By default `git clone` downloads the entire history of all branches.  You can give it options to tell it to download less, if you know you need less, but the default is to download everything so that you can later perform any source control operation (other than syncing changes with another repo) without any required connectivity.  For details of the options, see the `git clone` docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) - especially `--single-branch`, `--depth`, and `--shallow-*` options.

None of this really has much of anything to do with the DAG representation.  That's really only important when thinking about how to navigate the objects in git, and in fact it's a mistake to think of deltas as following the DAG, since you'd generally get it backwards.

---

[1] There are two formats in which git stores the objects that make up a project history.  As new material is committed, it is stored in loose objects - complete copies of each version of each file - but even then, git never stores the *same* content twice.  So if a file is unchanged across 10 commits, then one copy of that file is stored.  Also, even in loose form the data is compressed.

Later, objects can be switched to a "packed" representation.  Among the optimizations done when packing is to find similar objects, and represent the *older* of the two as a delta from the *newer*.

---

[2] Some commands, like `rebase`, operate on the *patch* between a commit and its parent, and the documentation (like much git documentation) is a bit squishy with the terminology around those commands.  So unfortunately it's easy for the misconception that a commit is a list of changes to spread.

But even though some of the objects making up an older commit might be internally represented as deltas from other objects from newer commits, conceptually the commit *is* a snapshot.  If you tell git, e.g. with `--depth` options, to only download part certain commits, you'll still get the entire snapshot - not just the patches relative to previous commits.  Any subset of a repo that contains partial deltas without enough information to rebuild the snapshot (i.e. the commit) would be considered corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

`git clone` will download enough content to allow you to reach any commit in the history of any branch.

If you want to download only the top commit of each branch, or only a portion of the history of each branch (say : the last 10 commits), look at the following options :

- `--depth=x`
- `--shallow-since=date`
- `--shallow-exclude=revision`

These options can also be passed to `git fetch` or `git pull`.

---

Note, however, that git is geared towards transmitting all of the content efficiently :

- if a file is not modified (between two commits) it is only downloaded once
- all downloaded content is compressed (using `zlib`)
- it has a bunch of features to detect that 2 files are very similar and download only the diff (instead of twice the whole content)