# Do git commits with fast-forwards form a DAG that is its own transitive reduction?

Tags: git, graph-theory

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395521/dag-vs-tree-using-git) elucidates that git commits form a DAG, not necessarily a tree. A DAG that is not a tree results from a merge commit, which will have multiple parents.

Is it fair to say that when Git is allowed to fast-forward, the resulting structure will be a DAG that is equal to its own transitive reduction?

For example:

```
master   develop
  |         |
  v         v
  A <- B <- C
```

If you had `master` checked out and ran `git merge develop`, git would recognize that there's already a path from A to C and would not create a new one (aka a merge commit)—unless you force it to with `--no-ff`.

Comment: This seems unlikely to be a programming question.

Comment: The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26395521/1201103) was considered on-topic.