# How do I show tips that don't have a head in `git log --all`?

Tags: git

The jargon as I understand it:

- **tip**, a commit that has no children (only parents unless orphaned)
- **head**, a named reference, eg `master`, or anything "tree-ish" as http://git-scm.com/book names it.

Under normal circumstances I use the slightly more graphical permutation of git log all:

```
git log --all --color --oneline --graph --decorate
```

To create a tip with no head I did:

```
git checkout HEAD^
echo "" >> index.html
git commit -am "tip test"
```

At which point `git log --all` does show the tip, but only because it has a head, specifically `HEAD`.

```
git checkout master
```

And now that tip we've created is no longer reported by git log.

---

I understand that this behavior is by-design, and that `git reflog` can point out recent "commit-ish" references.

I'd really like a way to see all tips in `git log` (as its chronology is an important feature to my purposes).

I don't know a way to do this, short of creating temporary references to all deferenced `HEAD@{N}` entries before requesting a log (though an answer that uses such would still be acceptable presuming it cleaned up after itself)

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't know (or care) about unnamed tips. These are also known as ["dangling commits"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514659/git-what-is-a-dangling-commit-blob-and-where-do-they-come-from), and may be produced by normal interactions with Git (particularly `rebase`, `reset`, and `commit --amend`).

There is no way I know of to have `git log` show dangling commits.