# File associated with a dangling blob

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I ran `git fsck` and obtained the following:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2338/2338), done.
dangling blob b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7
```

From previous questions on dangling blobs (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514659/what-is-a-dangling-commit-and-a-blob-in-a-git-repository-and-where-do-they-come), for instance) it is clear that this is not something to worry about and that it is a normal part of garbage collection process. However, I would like to find out what exactly this blob corresponds to.

Can one get, for instance, some data of which date this blob was made? What is the directory structure/file name that this blob corresponds to?

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git) suggested to try `git show b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7` but this does not produce any text/human readable output. Perhaps this blob was referring to some nontext file/folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a blob (a file content), but its "dangling" status means it is not referenced by anything else, and that you won't find its *name* in git.

From your comment to @AntonioPetricca's answer : it is not a text file.

One way to get more indication is to store it on disk and use a utility such as `file` :

```
git show b16084cf... > myblob
file myblob
```

If you know what kind of files you have in your directory (images ? zip or gzip files ? office document ? other binary files ?) you may guess what kind of file it is, and try to open it with an appropriate program (an image editor, an archive reader, office ...)

---

A dangling blob shouldn't be packed with other objects, so you can get an indication of when it was created (e.g : `git add`ed) by looking at the creation date of :

```
ls -l .git/objects/b1/6084cf...
```

Comment: This really helped! The output now is `myblob: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 736x284, components 3` Is this the absolute limit upto which we can get information about this ?

Comment: yes, after the information obtained using your answer, I gather that this was a JPEG file. I opened `myblob` using a jpeg viewer and voila, I am actually able to see the contents. Domo ari gato.

Comment: Good ! You can get a guess of when it was added in git too (I updated my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Please try with `git cat-file -p b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of this is also not in human readable form.

Comment: Please, post the output you got. Thank you.

Comment: It is a huge bunch of garbage characters, the last line of which is: `e95ÿ 82é?øýfZÚë▼ð98߁}¦y9fb¶Üß`}¤o9f ☼;83לó91ÀÇ=MdÙÿ Èñ¨ÿ ׍¯þ8c¹ ♥ìzçý♦t¯ü↨Iÿ Çèû▲¹ÿ A↔+ÿ ♣Ò⌂ñú֢80?ÿ` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This method **cannot** answer the question. But it can help, if you want to find out tracked big files, including those that exist in the history but not in the latest revision.

---

A blob is an object of the content of a file. From the blob hash, we cannot tell which file has the content.

First we list all commit objects,

```
git cat-file --batch-all-objects --batch-check | grep commit
```

We would get something like

```
1ff20d2c13f216e96cf623238242661105a97b67 commit 230
26179ca322862f4f5f74e229d6d22dff739e588b commit 183
```

Each line has the hash of a commit object, the object type `commit` and its size in byte. To search a commit object for the blob `b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7`, we can use

```
git ls-tree -r 1ff20d2c13f216e96cf623238242661105a97b67 | grep b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7
```

If the blob is found, it would print something like

```
100644 blob b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7    path/to/foo.bar
```

So we can know the commit(s) that have the blob and its corresponding path or paths in the repository. To combine the commands,

```
git cat-file --batch-all-objects --batch-check | grep commit | while read osha1 otype osize;do
    result=$(git ls-tree -r $osha1 | grep -e b16084cfd9ca4429688cf5cf7a1948d4307f31f7)
    if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then
        echo commit: $osha1, $result
    fi
done
```

Comment: I was able to replicate the steps you have indicated. On putting the last set of commands into a `.sh` file and running it, there is no error and yet nothing displayed on the screen either. I would imagine that the particular blob was overwritten or rewritten, etc.

Comment: @ElpieKay : if it is a dangling blob, it won't be referenced by a tree or a commit ...

Comment: @LeGEC Ah, you're right. I made a mistake here.

Comment: @Tryer As LeGEC said, my answer is wrong. The method can't work on dangling blobs. It's dangling because no other objects use it.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you for your time regardless. I have learned more from all answers here.