# How to fix GIT error : HEAD: invalid reflog entry xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Tags: git, git-log

I have met an error before(GIT error: object file is empty)

[image: error_object_file_is_empty]

Then I used the method mentioned in [how to fix GIT error: object file is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty)
After I updated the HEAD pointer to a good object, it does work .but when I restart the machine ,the same error(object file is empty) occured. 
I tried `find . -type f -empty -delete` to delete all the empty files and type `git fsck --full` then the new error occured.(GIT error: HEAD: invalid reflog entry xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

[image: error_invalid_reflog_entry]

Is there anything wrong with my GIT? or just because of my bad operations?
And how to fix this problem?

Comment: First, please backup your whole repository just in case. Next, can you please try 'git update-ref -d' inside of the repository. This might help you overcome this issue, but I am not all that familiar with this specific one. If this doesn't work, let me know so I can try to assist more.. If its right, let me post an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 26):

The command to use is `git reflog expire --stale-fix --all`

The magic here is in the `--stale-fix` option which will prune any reflog entries that point to an unreachable commit and that refers to a missing object.

Comment: this worked to clean up all the errors i was getting in `git fsck --full`

Comment: after fixing the repo with the above commadn, should I do `git commit` and `git push`?

Comment: @arielma `git commit` and `git push` should now be OK (but better verify this with `git fsck --full`)

Comment: It didn't work for me, I got `fatal: bad tree object 727e795836deba03ac658a22f1e714ede7ea3c8a`

Comment: If you don't want to actually expire *anything* except the broken entries, you can additionally use `--expire=never`

Answer (score 1):

> The command to use is `git reflog expire --stale-fix --all`

But make sure to use Git 2.31 (Q1 2021)

"[`git reflog expire --stale-fix`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e68f62be8dd65cd181be20b414fa45126b39d481/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> can be used to repair the reflog by removing entries that refer to objects that have been pruned away, but was not careful to tolerate missing objects.

See [commit c809798](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c809798b2acf1afdeeea02a9175677590ad8d689) (10 Feb 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e68f62b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e68f62be8dd65cd181be20b414fa45126b39d481), 17 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`reflog expire --stale-fix`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c809798b2acf1afdeeea02a9175677590ad8d689): be generous about missing objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Whenever a user runs [`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c809798b2acf1afdeeea02a9175677590ad8d689/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> expire `--stale-fix`, the most likely reason is that their repository is at least *somewhat* corrupt.
> Which means that it is more than just possible that some objects are missing.
>
> If that is the case, that can currently let the command abort through the phase where it tries to mark all reachable objects.
>
> Instead of adding insult to injury, let's be gentle and continue as best as we can in such a scenario, simply by ignoring the missing objects and moving on.