# git push - How to fix Error remote: fatal: bad object HEAD?

Tags: git, gitlab

I did clone a master branch, created a new branch and made changes, commit and try to push using the following command:

**`git push origin myNewBranch`**, but I keep getting the following error:

```
remote: fatal: bad object HEAD
To https://gitlab.com/myProjectRepo/my-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] myNewBranch -> myNewBranch (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/myProjectRepo/my-app.git'
```

The error I get doesn't mention or point to any empty object file like [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty). And also it happens from my side when trying to `push` not `commit`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix GIT error: object file is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty)

Comment: what does `git fsck` tell you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like Gitlab got themselves into yet another SNAFU about 2-3 hours ago as of writing this answer, and the problem is on their side.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44068

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3139

Comment: I love real time answers