# How to prevent the following on pull: error: object file <file> is empty

Tags: git

When doing a git pull, sometimes I'm getting the following error:

```
error: object file .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7 is empty
fatal: loose object e6093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7 (stored in .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7) is corrupt
```

It doesn't happen too often, but often enough for me to have a look around for hints on how to prevent it from happening, but I can't find anything. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to prevent this or if I'm doing anything wrong?

To resolve, I've been running `git fsck` and getting more missing/corrupt files showing (quantity usually varies) like now:

```
error: object file .git/objects/dd/e924b37ff52fa6c2d06400f78f7e39e5ed6e35 is empty
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/dd/e924b37ff52fa6c2d06400f78f7e39e5ed6e35: No such file or directory
error: dde924b37ff52fa6c2d06400f78f7e39e5ed6e35: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/dd/e924b37ff52fa6c2d06400f78f7e39e5ed6e35
error: object file .git/objects/e5/24fe77212c65a8c63fc469fd78bcfe0c9a1ebe is empty
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/e5/24fe77212c65a8c63fc469fd78bcfe0c9a1ebe: No such file or directory
error: e524fe77212c65a8c63fc469fd78bcfe0c9a1ebe: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/e5/24fe77212c65a8c63fc469fd78bcfe0c9a1ebe
error: object file .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7 is empty
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7: No such file or directory
error: e6093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7
error: object file .git/objects/e9/667f6312eb5f8bdb17b836b7f6865fe8376add is empty
error: unable to mmap .git/objects/e9/667f6312eb5f8bdb17b836b7f6865fe8376add: No such file or directory
error: e9667f6312eb5f8bdb17b836b7f6865fe8376add: object corrupt or missing: .git/objects/e9/667f6312eb5f8bdb17b836b7f6865fe8376add
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (955/955), done.
error: object file .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7 is empty
fatal: loose object e6093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7 (stored in .git/objects/e6/093637c867f4e4dac46f28725b1897eac09ac7) is corrupt
```

I just remove those files, then run `git fetch`.

After that it's fine, and can be for a while.

(I'm new here, go easy on me...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix GIT error: object file is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty)

Comment: Is your drive failing? Are you storing your files in a service that changes them out from underneath you (e.g., Dropbox)?

Comment: Thanks. No nothing like that.