# Can't pull and push to Git

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a group project that I have been pulling and pushing to everyday. I tried to pull now but I get this message `Your repository has no remotes configured to pull from.`
When I write `git remote -v` in the terminal I get this

```
origin  https://github.com/Elmassri/SE-Project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Elmassri/SE-Project.git (push)
```

So I have no idea what the issue is and how to fix it.

I don't know if this is relevant but `git status` is giving me this

```
error: object file .git/objects/b6/8df11599b94d5dad001ac7bfff4b5cb07eb30b is empty
error: object file .git/objects/b6/8df11599b94d5dad001ac7bfff4b5cb07eb30b is empty
error: object file .git/objects/b6/8df11599b94d5dad001ac7bfff4b5cb07eb30b is empty
fatal: loose object b68df11599b94d5dad001ac7bfff4b5cb07eb30b (stored in .git/objects/b6/8df11599b94d5dad001ac7bfff4b5cb07eb30b) is corrupt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Git error: object file is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-to-fix-git-error-object-file-is-empty)

Comment: Restart *Visual Studio Code*

Comment: Your repository is (perhaps only slightly) damaged. It's not clear why. Possibilities include a failing disk drive in your laptop (this assumes you're on a laptop; adjust as needed) or trying to use a shared directory (e.g., Dropbox or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone the remote repository

```
git clone https://github.com/Elmassri/SE-Project.git
```