# When i do git "status" or "git log" after adding file to my local cloned repository it does not show the status nor commit history

Tags: git, git-log, git-status

My git on my local machine was working well initially doing all the work adding and commiting just fine, but after i switched off my computer and got back to it again when i do "git status" or "git log"
this displays:

```
error: object file .git/objects/c0/6ef4a52d58699bc1d3240720dfb86a7c5d87e0 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/c0/6ef4a52d58699bc1d3240720dfb86a7c5d87e0 is empty
fatal: bad object HEAD
```

Before switching it off i made sure to add and push all the work and changes i made and it responded just fine

I tried watching some YouTube videos that would maybe help my specific problem but i did not get the answer i needed

The last time it did this, i created another repository and moved my work there after cloning repository but this is the second time this is happening after i switch off my computer

Please...I would highly appreciate anyone willing to help me i am stuck

Comment: Did you store your git repo on a shared drive such as Google Drive, iCloud Drive, that sort of thing?

Comment: Thank you for responding , No i did not store it in any sort of drive

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706215/how-can-i-fix-the-git-error-object-file-is-empty